# Problem in Manual ID Code

Tags: c#

My Auto ID is already working. But, I tried a Manual ID code and insert the value in my database.. My Questions is how i able to get the value of the manual id. Yes, it's simple but not in a read only.

Please check my code:

Deleting - Its working!

```
CMSInsurance oInsuranceDelete = new CMSInsurance();
                            Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();

                            List<InsuranceLabel> lstName = oInsuranceDelete.RetrieveInsuranceList();
                            foreach (InsuranceLabel item in lstName)
                            {
                                var code = e.CommandArgument;
                                if (item.InsuranceCode.ID == code.ToString())
                                {
                                    oInsurance.InsuranceCode = item.InsuranceCode; //proper getting the value of Insurance Code instead of txtCode.text or  e.CommandArgument
                                    oInsuranceDelete.DeleteInsurance(oInsurance);
                                    bind();
                                }
                            }
```

Inserting Auto ID code - Its Working!

```
            oInsurance.Name = txtName.text // for string

            CMSInsurance oCMSInsurance = new CMSnsurance();
            oCMSInsurance.CreateInsurance(oInsurance);
```

Inserting Manual ID Code - Not working..

```
    //Get the Manual value of Insurance Code
    //For Insert a New Insurance
    CMSInsurance oCMSInsuranceManual= new CMSInsurance ();
    List<InsuranceLabel> lstList = oCMSInsuranceManual.RetrieveInsuranceList();
    foreach (InsuranceLabel item in lstList)
    {
        if (item.InsuranceCode.ID != Session["AutoCode"])
        {
        oInsurance.InsuranceCode = item.InsuranceCode; // I can't insert a string like txtCode.. is there anyway to solve this issue? 
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what field type is InsuranceCode ?

Comment: What database are you working against? MS SQL Server, Oracle, My SQL

Comment: @haknick i don't know.. I just their dll, Insurancecode - Describes a UserIdentifier

Comment: @cos, i'm using sql anywhere 11..

Comment: well, guys i'm only with the Insurance Api

Comment: what does not working indicate

Answer (score 0):

Like tSQL, SQL Anywhere does not '*normally*' allow for inserts into an identity field:

> SQL Server does not allow INSERTs into
>   identity columns unless the
>   identity_insert option is set to on

you can find this and more on SQL at [Sybase SQL Anywhere User's Guide](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/conn5/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/21145;pt=20660/%2a)